# Ensuring parameters of log linear model sum to 1

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, log-linear

I am training a log-linear model with parameters $\theta$ using SGD. I want to ensure that my parameters will end up being probabilities i.e. $\sum_i \theta_i = 1$.

One way to do this is by using lagrangian relaxation - but I was wondering if there are some simpler alternatives.

Can I simply "force" my $\theta$ to sum to 1 after each iteration, Is this what is meant by Projected Gradient Method?
I was only able to find a wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_approximation#Projected_Gradient_Descent) on this topic and the literature on this is not helping (too complex for me to understand)

Secondly if I simply want to make $\theta_i > 0 \forall i$ can I simply force to be to so.. by adding a bias term to all the parameters?

When is it ok to do such projections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the right idea: you *project* onto your constraint set; i.e., find the element in your constraint set that is nearest, in whatever norm you are using, to the unconstrained solution.  This works with any convex set. Yours is called the *probability simplex*.

There is a good treatment of this in Stephen Boyd's *Convex Optimization*. Also see [slides 11-13 here](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/proxop.pdf) and [Projection onto the probability simplex](https://eng.ucmerced.edu/people/wwang5/papers/SimplexProj.pdf).

Comment: Thanks @Emre, for the pointers. What about the second condition i.e. all parameters are greater or equal to 0?

Comment: It does not pose a problem. When you have multiple constraints, you just find the intersection. The non-negativity constraint is covered in all the links.